# MongoDB or ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Which one of them is good to use? I'm developing a application which will have the following functionalities.

- Multiple users
- Each user will have their own database
- Data objects will be different; like product, department etc...
- Need a faster search/retrieval of data
- Million of requests per seconds.
- Support for PHP is preferable but not necessary.

I've been searching for this from last couple of days but couldn't make a decision to use one of them.

I've read somewhere that we shouldn't use Elastic-Search as a independent database? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above database can do the following, but so can Oracles, Mysql, MariaDB, MSSql, Cassandra, Lucene and Solr.

The best advice i can give is for you to sit down and read pros and cons of all of those and use the one you find fit.

Answer (score 0):

The main question is do you or products administrators know those databases?

If i would be building that application i would use
MySQL or Cassandra for the main database and
Elasticsearch for the search.

I would never use Elasticsearch for main database as it isn't
build for that.